# Loading data into file geodatabase without rebuilding relationship classes manually?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, relationship-class

I have a file geodatabase with a few M-N composite relationships classes. Every few weeks or months I need to load new data into GDB tables; for this I need to delete the relationship classes, load the data and then rebuild the relationship classes using [table to relationship classes](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/java/gp_toolref/data_management_tools/table_to_relationship_class_data_management_.htm) GP tool.

Is there a way  to save Geoprocesing results so that processes will be simpler and I will not need to remember all the parameters of all the relationship classes?

Comment: "Copy as Python Snippet" could help you to remember all the parameters of a geoprocessing result. Just right-click on a finished geoprocess in the result window and choose it. Paste the result in a txt somewhere and you can reuse it later in the Python window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the ArcGIS [ModelBuilder](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002w00000001000000).

You can drag & drop the tools you're using right out of ArcToolbox to create your process into model builder, and then save it as one geoprocessing tool. Run that, and everything should rebuild the same way every time.

Answer (score 3):

You can save geoprocessing results with the mxd file.

Older geoprocessing can be accessed from ArcMap's Main Menu. (Geoprocessing > Results).

In there You can see all the pre processed geoprocessings!

[image]