# How load data into file geodatabase tables with relationship classes to non simple data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, geometric-network, relationship-class

Further to my earlier question ([Loading data into file geodatabase without rebuilding relationship classes manually?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115947/is-there-a-way-to-save-geoprocesing-results)), is there any way to load data into GDB tables with relationship classes to composite data as geometric network without making them simple first ?

I have a file geodatabase with few M-N composite relationships classes that contain geometric network. Every few weeks or month I need to load new data into GDB tables; for this I need to delete the relationship classes delete the geometric network, and than load the data using [The Simple Data Loader wizard](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003n0000003t000000) and then rebuild the relationship classes and rebuild the geometric network. when I'm trying this without deleting first I keep getting error message:

> Cannot load into non simple data

[image]

[image]

Comment: A few things. Copy and paste should bring the relationship classes with. I don't believe import does. Second, what kind of data is it? Feature classes? Network datasets? Etc.

Comment: I think it is related - the relationship is between simple junction of geometric network and a geodatabase table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try copy and paste. It should work better than the simple data loader. The simple data loader is only for "simple" data. Feature classes and tables.

Geometric networks are considered complex and most likely won't load with the simple data loader. That error is expected.

This article is from 9.3.1 but explains the problem. Use the object loader not the simple data loader.

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/dotnet/index.htm#geodatabases/loadin-1923012175.htm